# Retornar Time.zone.now em C#

Tags: c#

Em ruby on rails tem um comando `Time.zone.now` que me retorna a data e hora nesse formato => `Sun, 18 May 2008 14:30:44 EDT -04:00`

Eu preciso obter esse mesmo retorno de time zone só que no C#

Alguém tem ideia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O equivalente do comando em Ruby é [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dataAtual = DateTime.Now;
```

O problema é que o [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.DateTime(v=vs.110).aspx) do C# não guarda informações de *timezone*, então [o deus do C# deu essa solução aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246529/1314276):

```
public struct DateTimeWithZone
{
    private readonly DateTime utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo timeZone;

    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZone); 
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public DateTime UniversalTime { get { return utcDateTime; } }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get { return timeZone; } }

    public DateTime LocalTime
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, timeZone); 
        }
    }        

    public override String ToString() 
    {
        return LocalTime.ToString() + " " + TimeZone.ToString();
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var dataComTimeZone = new DateTimeWithZone(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
// dataComTimeZone.TimeZone retorna a TimeZone
// dataComTimeZone.LocalTime retorna a data atual
// dataComTimeZone.ToString() retorna os dois juntos
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X4Tj4I).

Talvez não tenha ficado exatamente no formato do Ruby, mas é algo bem próximo.

Answer (score 1):

O mais próximo que consegui chegar do comando Ruby está abaixo:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime agora = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string ano = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            string dia = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
            string diaNome = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");
            string mesNome = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
            Console.Write(diaNome, new CultureInfo("en-US"));  // Displays Wed
            Console.Write(dia);
            Console.Write(mesNome, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            Console.Write(ano);
            Console.Write(agora.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

            TimeZoneInfo universalHora = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            Console.WriteLine(universalHora);
        }
    }
}
```

Utilizei também o DateTime e o TimeZoneInfo, mas de uma forma mais robusta e simples. Você pode concatenar os valores e deixar parecido com o formato do Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui uma solução possível, com algumas concatenações:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString() +",  "+ DateTime.Now.ToString("dd  MM  yyyy hh:MM:ss") +" "+TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString());
```

saída:

> Friday, 26 06 2015 04:06:24 (UTC-03:00) Brasília